# restricting number of connections in java socket server

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, serversocket, threadpoolexecutor

I have created a Java socket server which creates a socket server on a specified port and then spawns a RecordWriter object to perform some operation on the data stream obtained from each connection.

I start the program with port as 61000 and numthreads as 2.
I also started 3 clients to connect to it.
On the client side I could see that all 3 of them connected to the receiver however, the receiver logs indicated only two of them connected.

`netstat -an|grep 61000|grep -i ESTABLISHED`

indicated total 6 connections as the client and server are being run on the same machine.
My doubts are:

1. Why does the client log for the third time show that it could connect to the program on 61000 while I am using the backlog of 2. Also `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numThreads);` is allowing only 2 clients to be connected.
2. Although the server.accept happens in the MyWriter.java and there is no indication in logs that the 3rd client could connect, why does netstat show this as an Established connection

Here are my codes:

**MyReceiver.java**

```
package com.vikas;

import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class MyReceiver{

    protected int serverPort = -1;
    protected int numThreads = -1;

    protected boolean isStopped = false;
    protected Thread runningThread = null;
    protected ExecutorService threadPool = null;

    protected static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(MyReceiver.class);
    protected static ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    protected static Map<String, String> mapConnections = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>();

    public MyReceiver(int port){
        this.serverPort = port;
    }

    public void run(int numThreads){
        this.threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numThreads);

        try {
            logger.info("Starting server on port " + this.serverPort);
            MyReceiver.serverSocket = new ServerSocket(this.serverPort, numThreads);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //throw new RuntimeException("Cannot open port " + this.serverPort, e);
            logger.error("Cannot open port " + this.serverPort, e);
        }

        while(!isStopped()){
            this.threadPool.execute(new MyWriter());
        }


        if(MyReceiver.mapConnections.isEmpty()){
            this.threadPool.shutdown();
            //System.out.println("Server Stopped after shutdown.") ;
            logger.info("Server Stopped after shutdown.");
        }
    }


    public synchronized boolean isStopped() {
        return this.isStopped;
    }

    public synchronized void stop(){
        this.isStopped = true;
        try {
            MyReceiver.serverSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //throw new RuntimeException("Error closing server", e);
            logger.error("Error closing server", e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if(args.length != 2){
            System.out.println("Number of input arguements is not equal to 4.");
            System.out.println("Usage:  java -cp YOUR_CLASSPATH -Dlog4j.configurationFile=/path/to/log4j2.xml com.vikas.MyReceiver  <port>  <number of threads>");
            System.out.println("java -cp \"$CLASSPATH:./MyReceiver.jar:./log4j-api-2.6.2.jar:./log4j-core-2.6.2.jar\" -Dlog4j.configurationFile=log4j2.xml com.vikas.MyReceiver  61000 2");
        }
        int port = Integer.parseInt(args[0].trim());
        int numThreads = Integer.parseInt(args[1].trim());

        final MyReceiver myConnection = new MyReceiver(port, topic, brokers);
        myConnection.run(numThreads);

        /*Thread t = new Thread(myConnection);
        t.start();*/


        try {
            Thread.sleep(20000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            //e.printStackTrace();
            logger.error("Something went wrong", e);
        }
        //System.out.println("Stopping Server");
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                logger.info("SocketServer - Receive SIGINT!!!");
                logger.info("Stopping Server");

                if(!myConnection.isStopped()){
                    myConnection.stop();
                }
                logger.info("Server Stopped successfully");

                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
                catch (Exception e) {}
            }
        });
        //myConnection.stop();
    }
}
```

**MyWriter.java**

```
package com.vikas;

import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;



public class MyWriter implements Runnable{

    protected String topic = null;
    protected String brokers = null;

    protected static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(MyWriter.class);

    public MyWriter () {

    }


    public void run() {
        while(!MyReceiver.serverSocket.isClosed()){
            Socket server = null;
            try {
                server = MyReceiver.serverSocket.accept();
                //System.out.println("Just connected to " + server.getRemoteSocketAddress());
                logger.info("Just connected to " + server.getRemoteSocketAddress());
                MyReceiver.mapConnections.put(server.getRemoteSocketAddress().toString().trim(), "");

                //change for prod deployment //change implemented
                String key = null;
                String message = null;

                char ch;
                StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder();
                int value = 0;


                try {
                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(server.getInputStream())); 
                    while((value = in.read()) != -1){
                        ch = (char)value;
                        if(ch == 0x0a){
                            //msg.append(ch);
                            //System.out.println(msg);

                            message = msg.toString().trim();

                            //code change as part of testing in prod
                            if(message.length() != 0){
                                //do something
                                msg.setLength(0);
                            }
                            else{
                                logger.error("Blank String received");
                                msg.setLength(0);
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                            msg.append(ch);
                        }
                    }
                    logger.info("Closing connection for client :" + server.getRemoteSocketAddress());
                    //System.out.println("Closing connection for client :" + this.getClientSocket().getRemoteSocketAddress());
                    server.close();
                    MyReceiver.mapConnections.remove(server.getRemoteSocketAddress());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    //report exception somewhere.
                    //e.printStackTrace();
                    logger.error("Something went wrong!!", e);
                }
                finally{
                    producer.close();
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                if(MyReceiver.serverSocket.isClosed()) {
                    //System.out.println("Server was found to be Stopped.");
                    logger.error("Server was found to be Stopped.");
                    logger.error("Error accepting client connection", e);
                    break;
                }
            }           
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: `myConnection.run(numThreads);` - This ia *never* a good sign - you must use `myConnection.start(numThreads);` note the `start`.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon In this case it's just a method name. myConnection is of type `MyReceiver` which does not implement Runnable. I wouldn't name it "run" nut it's not wrong.

Comment: @Fildor - Understood - not the issue in question. Needed pointing out though.

Comment: "while(!isStopped()){
            this.threadPool.execute(new MyWriter());
        }" - This is REALLY bad! I wonder why you do not have issues with this. It will fill up your queue until the Program is stopped!

Comment: Connection: You need to separate "connection" on TCP layer and Application layer. In your receiver you conceive a client as "connected" when you have a thread taking on it and accept the connection. On Network level the connection is considered as established when the two machines have built up the comm channel ( all that SYN, ACK ... ). Which is two different definitions of "connected".

Comment: @Fildor, the idea behind doing the same is to have one instance of Mywriter class handle stream of data per connection.

Comment: I get the idea. But this is not how you should do it. `accept` will block. So if you call accept on one thread it will block until there is actually a connection request. In that case you will be returned the Socket instance which you can then put into a runnable (let's call it a SocketHandler) and have it executed by the pool. Then you can iterate to the next `accept` call. If you want to restrict the number concurrent Handlers, you can keep track of their number and only accept if slots are free.

Comment: @Fildor, Why do you think its a bad idea to do that?

Comment: @Fildor, I am unable to understa nd your point here, can you please elaborate?

Comment: Did you step through or monitor your application? You have a near-infinite loop that fills the Executor's queue with MyWriter instances. If your Applications runs long enough it will run into memory issues.

Comment: But I have limited the  Threadpool size with numthreads. Lets say if numThreads is 20, in that case there won't be more than 20 instances of MyWriter

Comment: No - there won't be more than 20 threads. But your WorkQueue is unbounded. Try to make an output in the loop and see what happens. If your assumption is correct, there should be only 20 outputs ..."Creates a thread pool that reuses a fixed number of threads **operating off a shared unbounded queue**." - See [Executors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool(int))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `backlog` parameter of the `ServerSocket` constructor restricts the size of the incoming connection queue not the total number of times you are allowed to successfully call `accept()`. If you want to restrict the number of active connections you need to keep track of how many connections you've accepted then when you hit your threshold don't call `accept()` again until at least one of the active connections has been closed.

```
while(!MyReceiver.serverSocket.isClosed()){
        Socket server = null;
        try {
            server = MyReceiver.serverSocket.accept();
            //System.out.println("Just connected to " + server.getRemoteSocketAddress());
            logger.info("Just connected to " + server.getRemoteSocketAddress());
            MyReceiver.mapConnections.put(server.getRemoteSocketAddress().toString().trim(), "");

            if (activeConnections == maxConnections) break; // exit accept loop
```

Comment: Thanks @SpaceghostAli!! I just have on doubt, when you said "The backlog parameter of the ServerSocket constructor restricts the size of the incoming connection queue not the total number of times you are allowed to successfully call accept() "  ..... what queue are we talking about and how does this queue affect my socket server?

Comment: @VikasSaxena He is talking about the incoming connection queue, or 'backlog' queue, and it affects your server by limiting the number of inbound connections that can exist without having been returned by `accept()` yet.